# Scala sequence group by enum exhaustively

Tags: scala, enums, sequence, scala-collections

I want to group a sequence by an enum exhaustively, meaning that if the sequence contains 0 occurrences of an enum, include it in the grouping anyway.

For example, if I have an enum like

```scala
object Color extends Enumeration {
  type Color = Value
  val Red, Green, Blue = Value
}
```

an object that uses the enum

```scala
case class Furniture (
  name: String,
  color: Color.Value
)
```

A list of objects

```scala
val furnitures = Seq(
  Furniture("Chair", Color.Red), 
  Furniture("Table", Color.Red),
  Furniture("Bed", Color.Blue),
  Furniture("Sofa", Color.Blue)
)
```

How can I group `furnitures` by `Color` such as I have:

```scala
Map(
  Color.Red -> List(Furniture("Chair", Color.Red), Furniture("Table", Color.Red)),
  Color.Green -> List(),
  Color.Blue -> List(Furniture("Bed", Color.Blue), Furniture("Sofa", Color.Blue))
)
```

Using the `Seq.groupBy` method, `Color.Green` is not shown as a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go through all colors and check if map created by `groupBy` contains any list and if not just add default empty list:

```
val grouped = furnitures.groupBy(_.color)
val result = Color.values.map(c => (c, grouped.getOrElse(c, Nil))).toMap

println(result) 
//Map(Red -> List(Furniture(Chair,Red), Furniture(Table,Red)), Green -> List(), Blue -> List(Furniture(Bed,Blue), Furniture(Sofa,Blue)))
```